# CORS Error: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check whilst having a webconfig

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, cors

I am creating my agency website with Springboot and Angular.
I just added the feature to add blog posts with a tinymce editor. Everytime I try to add a post, it gives me the error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/blogs/createBlog' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

Whilst I have a webconfig configured in the backend.
It started right after I added the http interceptor in the front end.

Here is some relevant front end code:

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpClientInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private $localStorage: LocalStorageService) {
  }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const token = this.$localStorage.retrieve("authenticationToken");
    console.log('jwt token ' + token);

    if (token) {
      const cloned = req.clone(
        {
          headers: req.headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
        }
      );

      return next.handle(cloned);
    } else {
      return next.handle(req);
    }
  }
}
```

```
export class BlogService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  addBlog(blogPayload: BlogPayload) {
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/api/blogs/createBlog', blogPayload)
  }
}
```

```
export class BlogFormComponent {
  blogForm: FormGroup;
  title = new FormControl('')
  body = new FormControl('')
  blogPayload: BlogPayload;


  constructor(
    private blogService: BlogService,
    // private toastr: ToastrService
  ) {
    this.blogForm = new FormGroup({
      title: this.title,
      body: this.body
    })

    this.blogPayload = {
      id: '',
      content: '',
      title: '',
      email: '',
    }
  }

  addPost() {
    this.blogPayload.content = this.blogForm.get('body')?.value;
    this.blogPayload.title = this.blogForm.get('title')?.value;
    this.blogService.addBlog(this.blogPayload).subscribe(data => {
      // this.toastr.success("Blog with title: '" +this.title + "' has been successfully added")
      console.log("success")
    }, err => {
      // this.toastr.error("There was a problem with adding the blog. Try again later or contact the admin.")
      console.log("error")
    })
  }
}
```

Here is some relevant backend code:

```
@Configuration
public class Webconfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOriginPatterns("*")
                .allowedMethods("*")
                .maxAge(3600L)
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .allowCredentials(true);
    }


}
```

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
    }

    @Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/**")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/client/**", "/api/project/**", "/api/provider/**", "/api/team/**", "/api/category/**", "/api/blogs/**")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/contact/**")
                .authenticated()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/contact/**")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/client/**", "/api/project/**", "/api/provider/**", "/api/team/**", "/api/category/**", "/api/auth/**", "/api/blogs/**")
                .authenticated()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/api/contact/**", "/api/client/**", "/api/project/**", "/api/provider/**", "/api/team/**", "/api/category/**", "/api/blogs/**")
                .authenticated()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/api/contact/**", "/api/client/**", "/api/project/**", "/api/provider/**", "/api/team/**", "/api/category/**", "/api/blogs/**")
                .authenticated()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }



    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


}
```

I am entirely lost and I dont understand why this is happening whilst it wasnt happening before.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I am now seeing that I have a crap ton of dependency conflicts in the frontend. Will try to fix those to see if that could fix the problem!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).